# How do I print a queue?

Tags: c++, stl, queue

I am trying to print a `queue` below. I have tried the idea of creating a temp `queue` and writing into it then writing it back.

But it's not working.

Or what am I missing here?

```cpp
for(int i = 1; i<myQueue.size(); i++)
{
    queue<int> tempQueue;

    cout << myQueue.front() << endl;
    MytempQueue.push(myQueue.front());
    myQueue.pop();

    myQueue.push(myTempQueue.back());
}
```

My queue is `queue<int> myQueue;`

Essentially, I want to print this `queue` without emptying it. But I am stuck here.

Comment: Just a hint: if printing is a frequent, important operation in your code, then perhaps a queue is just the wrong choice for the data type, and you may be better of with a different kind of container altogether.

Comment: @ChristianHackl What would be that container?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no efficient way to do this<sup>*</sup>. But you can do the following:

1. Make a copy of the queue.
2. Iterate over the copy, printing the front, then popping it.

For example:

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
    
void print_queue(std::queue<int> q)
{
  while (!q.empty())
  {
    std::cout << q.front() << " ";
    q.pop();
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::queue<int> q;
  for (auto i : {1,2,3,7,4,9,7,2,4}) q.push(i);
  print_queue(q);
}
```

<sup>* There's a hack using inheritance. `std::queue` has a protected member `C` which is the underlying container holding the data. You could inherit from `std::queue` and add methods to do the printing using `C`. But you have to be fully aware of the implications of inheriting from a type that is not necessarily designed for that.</sup>

Comment: How do i make a copy of the queue? Thats what im trying to do. Pseudo code help would be awesome!

Comment: `queue<int> copy = myQueue;`

Comment: @user3398034 [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) have both a [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/queue) and an [copy assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/operator%3D).

Comment: @user3398034 I added an example

Comment: If you have custom class type like queue<classType> then we can use q.front().yourMethod() to get or set values

Comment: @juanchopanza *"There's a hack using inheritance. `std::queue` has a protected member C which is ..."*       Could you please share that hack or redirect me to some resources where I can read more about them? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**for(int i = 1; i<myQueue.size(); i++)**

Loop should start with 0, or check condition should be <=

```
queue<int> myQueue;
myQueue.push(1);
myQueue.push(2);
myQueue.push(3);
myQueue.push(4);
myQueue.push(5);

for (size_t i = 0; i < myQueue.size(); i++)
{
    cout << myQueue.front() << endl;
    myQueue.push(myQueue.front());
    myQueue.pop();
}
```

Comment: This empties the queue. The question requested a solution that doesn't empty the queue.